# Convert “type” column into individual columns with count in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 1 column and 1 value

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("recommended: 882, meh: 501, exceptional: 283, skip: 185"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I am trying to convert this `type` column into multiple individual columns of comments with their count

My **desired output** is

```
recommended meh exceptional skip
        882 501         283  185
```

I can do this in R like this

```
 library(tidyr)
    df %>%
      separate_rows(type, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
      separate(type, c('type', 'value'), sep = ':\\s*', convert = TRUE) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value)
```

I am trying to implement it in Python. I am a beginner, trying to learn and so any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a pandas dataframe. what you have shared is an R dataframe

Answer (score 0):

*I have a dataframe with 1 column and 1 value*: Your problem seems to be just parsing one single string. So Pandas/DataFrame would be overkill.

For example:

```
import re
s = "recommended: 882, meh: 501, exceptional: 283, skip: 185"
dict(re.findall('([\w]*):\s(\d+)', s))
```

Output:

```
{'recommended': '882', 'meh': '501', 'exceptional': '283', 'skip': '185'}
```

That said, here you go with a DataFrame solution:

```
df['type'].str.extractall('([\w]*):\s(\d+)').set_index(0).T
```

Output:

```
0 recommended  meh exceptional skip
1         882  501         283  185
```